# Wamp and file permissions using windows

Tags: windows, permissions, wamp, chmod

Apologies if already answered. None of the listed answers seemed satisfactory.

I'm using WAMP to build a site (obviously windows). Folder for images needs permissions turned on so they appear on the site. Everytime I use "Properties" on the folder, it reverts back to read only. Altering things in the advanced toolbars and trying to make it permission enabled don't help.

Anyone know what the alternatives to CHMOD or the equivalent to it in this environment? (Windows/WAMP etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the issue. Had nothing to do with file permissions - but with CMS specific Tags.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give permission to the "IUSR_Machinename" in the specific folder. Just search properties window clicking with the right button over the folder, go to security settings and add the "IUSR_machinename" user with the rights you need.

Comment: Thnks for that tidbit. I will look into trying that.